# How to get this text effect in Fireworks? (or at a push, Photoshop!)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-fireworks, text

I love the effect on this logo and was wondering if anyone knew any tutorials to help get a similar effect?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: There are a number of effects going on here, which one were you after specifically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear that there are three main effects going on - a gradient fill, a shape outline, and a drop shadow. All three can be applied using Layer Styles in Photoshop. You should then be able to bring this layer into Fireworks either as a .psd file or as a .png. There may be a way to do it in Fireworks but doing it in Photoshop is much, much easier. It also gives you the ability to go back and change your text without having to re-do all your settings. 

**Step 1:** Type your text in using whatever font you are looking for. Double-click the text layer to bring up the Layer Style menu / dialog.
**Step 2:** Select "Drop Shadow" from the list on the left, make sure the check box is selected, and set your parameters for the drop shadow. It doesn't look like they're using a very large drop shadow, but depending on the size of your text you'll want to play a little.
**Step 3:** Select "Gradient Overlay", again making sure that the check box is selected, and make your adjustments. It looks like this gradient is pretty much straight up and down, so you'll want to leave your angle for 90. Click on the gradient swatch to change the colors of the gradient (it looks like they're using a light blue and a slightly deeper blue for this one).
**Step 4:** Select "Stroke", ensure the check box is selected, and use the slider to adjust the width of the stroke. it looks like they're using an "Outside" stroke but you can experiment. Change the color (they're using white) by clicking on the color swatch in the "Fill Type" area. 

Play with the settings until you find something you like; the more you play the easier it gets.

Comment: I don't recall if Fireworks has an outside stroke option. If not, layer the type twice, giving the lower type the stroke, the upper the gradient.

Answer (score 3):

I want to learn Fireworks and recreating the text effect on this logo has given me just the little kickstart I needed to play about with things.

As per lawndartcatcher's answer, type in your text in whichever font you wish.

Click your bucket fill colour palette drop-down and select 'Fill Options...'

Select 'Gradient' from the drop down, select 'Linear' then click the 'Edit...' button and add in your to and from colours with any stop-offs in between.

Click the stroke colour palette drop down and select 'Stroke Options...'

Select 'Pencil', 1 pixel soft, and change your tip size to something larger, depending on the size of text you've used. Leave whatever the default texture is making sure it's set at 0% and select 'Outside Path' from the next drop-down then tick the 'Fill over stroke' checkbox.

The last thing to add is the drop shadow. Do this by clicking the '+' button next to 'Filters' in your properties panel, the 'Shadow and glow' then 'drop shadow'. I found that '4' for distance, 15% opacity, '2' softness and 270 angle looked about right.

I ended up with this (I've not got the correct font):

[image]

And that ends my very first piece of design I've ever done in Fireworks. I quite enjoyed that!

Hope that helps!